# ejabberd xmpp set presence for offline user

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

For a status application we are using ejabberd xmpp server.

At some times, a status must be set from a web server for a user.
It may be that the user doesn't have an active xmpp session.

I tried with https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#set-presence, but this only works for an active session and valid resource.

How can we "override" the presence of a specified user?

Answer (score 0):

> It may be that the user doesn't have an active xmpp session.

When a XMPP client logins to an XMPP account and sets a resource, sends a presence with a status, then a XMPP session is established.

If an account doesn't have an active xmpp session, then there isn't any status to be set, no resource, and no presence to update, right?